# My android application hangs in SmartTV

Tags: android, performance

I have an android application which runs in a few different Android system. It works in all my mobile, tablet and one of my SmartTV system. But it only hangs in another different SmartTv system. My question is how I'm able to debug this issue? Currently I have no way to connect to this smart tv for debugging. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: This application crash or  hangs ?

Comment: The app hangs sometimes only on one smartTV. It's working very well in my mobile app used by thousands of users. And another smartTV used by hundreds of users.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot debug it directly than I would try logging it expictly. E.g. add on every relevant point a http call where you log what happend.

Comment: The problem is I don't know where to start. In another words, how am I supposed to debug ?

Comment: I use USB to install. But the cable connect the phone and my computer is not the same type so that I can't connect my TV to my computer.

Comment: The TV is network connected. And I'm use thumb drive to upload my apk. There are two usb ports. But the port is not the same as the phone so that I can't  use the same cable to connect the TV to my computer.